# Changing the address a pointer is pointing to

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I want to change different pointer (different types), that they point to NULL/0/nullptr..., but I have to use a variable to do this! 
 Generally I understand pointers and I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it.

So I need something like

```
int NULLPOINTER = nullptr;                 // data type can change if needed
int* myIntPointer = NULLPOINTER;
float* myFloatPointer = NULLPOINTER;
foo* myFooPointer = NULLPOINTER;
```

As shown above, this is not possible because of the invalid conversion error (int to int*/float*/foo*).

So how can I archiv this?
As requested a more complex example for clarification:

```
class foo
{
    float floatVar;
};

class bar
{
    char charVar;
};

void changeSomething(bar* pBarTmp)
{
    /* pGlobal is a member of another class and the type is depends on the method */
    pGlobal = pBarTmp;
}

int main()
{
    /* Working just fine */
    int var = 1;
    int *pointer  = &var;

    /* Also working fine */
    foo *pointer = 0;    //nullptr or NULL or __null (compiler dependend)

    /* Not working because newAddress is int and not bar* / foo* / int* */
    int newAddress = 0;

    // Only one of the following is present, it depends on the 
    // method/class (just for visualization) 
    bar *pointer = newAddress;               
    foo *pointer = newAddress;
    int *pointer = newAddress;

    changeSomething (pointer);
}
```

I am not allowed to change `int newAddress;` into `int* newAddress;`. 
 Overall I won't use something else than `NULL / 0 / nullptr / ...`

Another difficulty is, that I cannot use reinterpret_cast cause of coding guidelines.

Comment: If your goal is to set the pointers to null why are you trying to use other values?  Just use `my_pointer = nullptr;` and you're done.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am doing some FITs (fault injection tests) and I am doing this with macros. I have to give the macro a variable, so I cannot use "null" directly.

Comment: then use `int* dummy = nullptr; my_pointer = dummy;`

Comment: @xMutzelx: I think what's confusing people is that you only used `int*`, but you're specifically asking about "different pointer types". Update your example to reflect this, then clarify it in the question, and I think the downvotes might go away.

Comment: @AndyG Thank you for your advice, I tried to improve my question further, to clarify the problem a bit better. I have a question-ban, so can you pls check if my question is still worth a minus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `int* p3 = 1;             //Error invalid conversion from int to int`

You can directly set the address of a pointer in C++

```
int* p3 = reinterpret_cast<int*>( 0x00000001 );
```

But its not good idea since you dont know where the pointer points in memory and de-referencing would lead to undefined behavior.

Its invalid conversion because `1` has type `int` and it's not possible to assign to pointer variable `int *` without cast.

---

> `int* p2 = 0;             //p is a NULL-pointer`

Pointers pointing to null should be initialized

```
int* p2 = nullptr;
```

instead of

```
int* p2 = 0;
```

Since `C++11` you can create an instance of `std::nullptr_t` and assign it to pointers.

```
std::nullptr_t initAddr;
int* p2 = initAddr;
```

Comment: Initializing with 0 is just fine, and a matter of taste. The real advantages of `nullptr` are in template deduction and overload resolution, which don't apply here.

Comment: Yes but somebody could read it as `int p2 = 0`.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer, it helped me a lot.

Comment: You are welcome, iam glad it helped you :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Changing the adress a pointer is pointing to
>
> My goal is to change the adress of different pointer types to NULL

By assignment:

```
int* p = nullptr;
```

> and I have to use a variable to do this.
>
> ```
> int newAdress = 0;
> int* p2 = newAdress;
> ```

The bug here is that `newAdress` has the wrong type. The compiler helps you out by telling you that is wrong. You will need to use a pointer (of compatible type) variable to assign a pointer:

```
int* newAdress = nullptr;
// ^ see here, a pointer

int* p2 = newAdress;
```

---

> ```
> int* p3 = 1;
> ```

This assignment makes little sense in most cases. 1 is not null, nor is there usually a guarantee that there is an `int` object at that memory location.

Nevertheless, there are some special cases where you need a particular address value. That can be achieved with casting:

```
int* p3 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(1);
```

If you don't know of such cases, then you don't need to do it. If you don't have such case, then using pointer to the arbitrary memory location has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 came with  `nullptr`, and `nullptr` has type [`std::nullptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t). You can create an instance of this and assign:

```
int* p1;
char* p2;
double* p3;
std::nullptr_t newAddress;
p1 = newAddress;
p2 = newAddress;
p3 = newAddress;
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e8WFXYVaBBfZpoi2)

This satisfies having your `NULL` in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that `int*` ≠ `int`. You shouldn't directly change the address. That seems pointless, since every program run variables are saved in different parts of memory with different addresses.

It only works with `NULL`, which is the same as 0, but should be avoided in C++ 11, where you should use `nullptr` for safety.

What you can do is set the address with the address-of-operator `&`:

```
int a;
int* b = &a;
```